# VM ESXI on HP mini Elitedesk 800g2

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Is it possible to install Esxi 5.5 or 6.5 directly onto  a Hp Elitedesk mini 800 g2? I was successfully able to get up in running into VM workstation pro on windows 7 but having problems installing directly to the mini. When I try to install onto the hp mini I get a blank black screen after all the files load up from the DVD. I'm not sure if there is some kind of driver problem. I am aware ESXI is for servers and its compatible with certain hardware. I wanted to know if it was possible to install it to the mini without running from windows?

Comment: ESXi hardware compatability is well documented, have you verified, your hardware meets those requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the latest version of ESXI, problems solved. I guess 5.5 version is too buggy. I am running esxi 6.5  from USB.